# When connecting from SQL using ODBC to openedge getting error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, openedge

When trying to connect using ODBC from SQL to OpenEdge getting the below error message.

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Name cannot be NULL. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15004)

Comment: Sounds like you are using a MsSQL ODBC-driver or something similar when you should be using a Progress OpenEdge ODBC-driver?

Comment: Yes using Progress ODBC driver for the that particular version of progress, but it is happening only above SQL 2014